# Memory management between ARC and non-ARC frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a framework A which is ARC. This consumes some API's from non ARC framework B.

Framework B sample code (non ARC):

```
@interface Settings : NSObject {
    NSDictionary* settings;
}
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(NSString*)key;
@end
@implementation Settings
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [settings objectForKey: key];
}
@end
```

Framework A sample code (ARC):

```
{
    // ...
    SEL stringForKeySelector = @selector(stringForKey:);
    NSMethodSignature *stringForKeySignature = [[Settings class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:stringForKeySelector];
    NSInvocation *stringForKeyInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:stringForKeySignature];
    [stringForKeyInvocation setSelector:stringForKeySelector];
    [stringForKeyInvocation setTarget:SettingsObject];

    NSString *Key = @"KEY";
    [stringForKeyInvocation setArgument:& Key atIndex:2];
    [stringForKeyInvocation invoke];

    NSString *value = nil;
    [stringForKeyInvocation getReturnValue:& value];

    // ...
}
```

Object from settings dictionary gets released after executing above code in framework A.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer:
Thanks Chuck for pointing out problems with NSInvocation and ARC.
I got around this problem by returning basic data types.

Comment: This code doesn't even make sense. Your `settings` instance variable wouldn't be available from a class method. Why are you even using `NSInvocation`, anyway?

Comment: That was a mistake, edited code. I use NSInvocation because, Framework B is not available in all projects where Framework A is used. I have dynamic checks to validate Framework B and invoke only if class is present. Obviously I kept sample code simple by not adding all checks.

Comment: @Vinay You don't have to do that.  Objective-C is already dynamic by default.  Just check if a given class or framework is available, then call a method like you would normally.

Comment: @Darren Yes, using respondstoselector and performselector, I can achieve it for certain functions with certain types of return values. But with multiple arguments and mix of basic data types and objc types, NSInvocation is better.

Comment: @Vinay No, you just need to declare the method signature somewhere (such as in your Settings header).  You're then free to attempt to call that method on any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with memory management between ARC and non-ARC code. Instead, this is because NSInvocation does not work very cleanly with ARC. It's usually preferable to avoid NSInvocation anyway, and doubly so with ARC. There is usually a better choice for anything you'd use NSInvocation for. If you must use NSInvocation, you'll need to remember that it just deals with raw byte blobs and doesn't handle object ownership at all, so passing an ARC-managed pointer is not kosher. You'll want to have the return-value variable be a void pointer, and then use a bridging cast to assign it to a normal object-type variable.

Comment: Thanks, NSInvocation was the problem. I switched to basic data types to get around problem with returning Objective-C objects.